# Hibernate SessionFactory vs Spring LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to move a spring3.2.x + hibernate4.x setup from a xml to java configuration.
Heres a snippet of the existing code:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class StockDaoImpl implements StockDao{

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;}
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
         this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void save(Stock stock){
        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try{
        session.save(stock);
        }
        finally{
        session.close();
        }
    }
```

The spring config file

```
<!-- Stock Data Access Object -->
   <bean id="stockDao" class="com.data.dao.StockDaoImpl" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
   </bean> 

    <bean id="dataSource">
.....
</bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" 
         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource">
          <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           ......
         </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
        .......
        </property> 
    </bean>
```

This works fine - but how do i re-define this config in java?
Heres an attempt -

```
@Bean
    public StockDao stockDao() {
        StockDaoImpl dao=new StockDaoImpl();
        dao.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
        return dao;
    }

......
   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
      sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { .....});
      sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

      return sessionFactory;
   }
```

But this wont compile as the `sessionFactory` being referred to is not Spring's LocalSessionFactoryBean?

How do I reconcile this?

Comment: This won't compile: what's the exact and complete compilation error? Why don't you use autowiring and classpath scanning instead of defining your DAO explicitely?

Comment: com\data\config\PersistenceConfig.java:32: setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.Sessi
onFactory) in com.data.dao.StockDaoImpl cannot be applied to (org.springframewor
k.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean)
                dao.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());

Answer (score 15, accepted):

LocalSessionFactoryBean is a `FactoryBean<SessionFactory>`. It means that it allows creating instances of SessionFactory.

So you just need

```
public StockDao stockDao() {
    StockDaoImpl dao=new StockDaoImpl();
    dao.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return dao;
}
```

But I wouldn't create DAOs explicitel like that. Simply annotate your DAO with @Repository, and autowire the session factory using @Autowired. Make sure the Java config class is annotated with `@ComponentScan("the.base.package.of.daos")`

Answer (score 1):

Missing getObject() call in return.
Substituite with `return sessionFactory.getObject()` (and change return type,too!)

Answer (score 1):

[JB Nizet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18012288/381083) helped me, but I needed to declare the beans separately for it to work:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean(final DataSource dataSource,
                                              final Properties hibernateProperties,
                                              final List<String> hibernateMappings) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    sessionFactoryBean.setMappingResources(hibernateMappings.toArray(new String[hibernateMappings.size()]));
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean) {
    return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```